# is this createCriteria() right.. using hibernatecriteriabuilder

Tags: hibernate, groovy

Can we use 2 groupProperty in projections as shown below. grauser is an object referenced field. is the query below right?

```
OnemonthList=TxnJan.createCriteria().list {   
        eq('graresource',resourceInstance)
        between('currentdate', fromDate, toDate)        

        projections {

        grauser {
          countDistinct('id')    
        }

        groupProperty('currentdate')
        groupProperty('eventdesc')
        order('currentdate', "asc")
            }                  
        }
```